# How to deal with pass a value twice in a PHP file

Tags: php

I am working on modification of a program. There are two value passes happened in one PHP file, and I get a notification from system like this:

```
Notice: Undefined index: content in /Users/alexhu/NetBeansProjects/menagerie/svn/trunk/apps/frontend/modules/legacy/legacy_lib/content/utilities/hraprint.php on line 23
```

And

```
Notice: Undefined index: isProvena in /Users/alexhu/NetBeansProjects/menagerie/svn/trunk/apps/frontend/modules/legacy/legacy_lib/content/utilities/hraprint.php on line 24
```

How to avoid it?

Comment: 1. Please show the code.  2. Please accept some of your earlier questions to get a better response.

Comment: On lines 23 and 24, you're using an array.  You're trying to access the indexes `content` and `isProvena` of that array.  Those indexes don't exist in the array.  Without any code, that's all I can say.  Besides maybe try `isset($array['content'])` and `isset($array['isProvena'])`.

Answer (score 2):

That error means you've basically got something like:

```
$my_arrray = array();

if ($my_array['content'] == ....) {
}
```

... attempting to access an index/key in an array which has not yet been defined. To guard against it, you'd need something like:

```
if (isset($my_array['content']) && ($my_array['content'] == ....)) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you are trying to use an index of an array which doesn't exist.

The error is stating what is wrong :-)

Answer (score 0):

You're simply trying to access `$array['content']` and `$array['isProvena']` in your code. Without the code we can't tell you anything though.